# array: how to return reference / pointer

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Hy everybody!

how to return an array reference / pointer in a function?

ex:

```
$a=array('given'=>array());

function getRef(&$ref){

//adds a child element to the given reference/pointer
$ref['test']=array();

//doesn't return the current reference/pointer
return $ref['test'];
}

//out: Array ( [given] => Array ( [test] => Array ( ) ) )
$p=getRef($a['given']);
print_r($a);

//out: same as above
//expected: ( [given] => Array ( [test] => Array ([test2] => Array ( ) ) ) )
$p['test2']=array();
print_r($a);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check the below it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this One

```
    <?php
$a=array('given'=>array());

function &getRef(&$ref){

//adds a child element to the given reference/pointer
$ref['test']=array();

//doesn't return the current reference/pointer
return $ref['test'];
}

//out: Array ( [given] => Array ( [test] => Array ( ) ) )
$p=&getRef($a['given']);
print_r($a);

//out: same as above
//expected: ( [given] => Array ( [test] => Array ([test2] => Array ( ) ) ) )
$p['test2']=array();
print_r($a);
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
function &getRef(&$ref){

return $ref['test'];
```

By using an ampersand at the start of a function, you return the refference of a varible instead of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$a=array('given'=>array());

function getRef(&$ref){

//adds a child element to the given reference/pointer
$ref['test']=array();

//doesn't return the current reference/pointer
return $ref['test'];
}

//out: Array ( [given] => Array ( [test] => Array ( ) ) )
$p=getRef($a['given']);
print_r($a);

//out: same as above
//expected: ( [given] => Array ( [test] => Array ([test2] => Array ( ) ) ) )
$p['given']['test']['test2']=array();
print_r($p);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass by reference you use the same variable inside the function as you do outside and you don't return a value. [PHP Manual - Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
$a = array('given' => array());

function getRef(&$a)
{
  $a['test']=array();   
}

// this now has the nested array test.
getRef($a['given']);
print_r($a);
```

If this is all your function is doing then I would advise to just set these nested arrays normally.

```
$b = ['given' => ['test' => ['test2' => []]]];
print_r($b);
```